# Factoring the powers of 2 in Python

Tags: python, bitwise, math-expression-eval

The powers of 2 are trivial to factor because all powers of 2 have one **1-bit** and the rest **0-bits**. Just iterate minus one 0-bit as follows: 10000,1000,100,10,1. And then convert the binary strings into base-10 and you got the factors for *powers of 2*.

Example

```
import operator
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce
import time

print('Find the factors of a power of 2')
print('This input number must be a power of 2')
X = 32

binary = "{0:b}".format(int(X))
l = len(binary)

# Checking if input is power of 2
# All binary strings that are a power of 2 must
# have only ONE 1 bit

if binary.count(str(1)) == 1:
  print('yes, this is a power of two')
else:
  print('no, this is not a power of 2')
  quit()  

start = (round(time.time() * 1000000))
count = 0
result = [];
for j in range(0, l):
        count = count + 1
        # create list of factors called result
        result.append(int(binary[0:l-count], 2))
        if len(result) == l-1:
          # I don't want to forget X itself is a factor
          result.append(X)
          end = (round(time.time() * 1000000))
          break

print(result)          
print('Factoring took', end-start, 'microseconds')
```

### Output

```
Find the factors of a power of 2
This input number must be a power of 2
yes, this is a power of two
[16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 32]
Factoring took 0 microseconds
```

### Question

What better names could I use to define my variables, and what could make the program run faster?

Is there a more efficient implementation to decide if a number is a power of 2?

Comment: have you considered using `<<` and `>>` ?

Comment: @impopularGuy I've been practicing python since August of last year and not exactly sure how to use that. Could you give an example?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600306/8363478) explains beautiful way to check whether a number is power of 2

Answer (score 2):

1. There should be some function definitions. `is_power_of_2`, `powers_of_2_below` and a `main`.
2. It's good practice to use an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard.
3. Please stop putting lots of spaces at the end of lines.
4. Many of the imports are not used.
5. Always indent with 4 spaces.

```py
import time


def is_power_of_2(X):
    binary = "{0:b}".format(int(X))
    return binary.count(str(1)) == 1


def powers_of_2_below(X):
    binary = "{0:b}".format(int(X))
    l = len(binary)
    count = 0
    result = [];
    for j in range(0, l):
        count = count + 1
        # create list of factors called result
        result.append(int(binary[0:l-count], 2))
        if len(result) == l-1:
            # I don't want to forget X itself is a factor
            result.append(X)
            break
    return result


def main(X):
    print('Find the factors of a power of 2')
    print('This input number must be a power of 2')
    if is_power_of_2(X):
        print('yes, this is a power of two')
    else:
        print('no, this is not a power of 2')
        quit()
    start = (round(time.time() * 1000000))
    result = factors_of_power_of_2(X)
    end = (round(time.time() * 1000000))
    print(result)
    print('Factoring took', end - start, 'microseconds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(X)
```

6. You can now use `return` rather than `quit` to exit `main`.
7. The code in `is_power_of_2` is fine. There are a couple other ways you can implement it but they're all pretty underwhelming.
8. By replacing `count` with `(j + 1)` we can remove the need for that variable.
9. By using `j` rather than `(j + 1)` we can remove the need for the `if` in the for.
10. To get `l` in `powers_of_2_below` we can use `X.bit_length()`.
11. We can instead use `1 << j` to build the value from `j` alone. This however will invert the output.

```py
import time


def is_power_of_2(x):
    binary = "{0:b}".format(int(x))
    return binary.count(str(1)) == 1


def powers_of_2_below(x):
    result = []
    for j in range(0, x.bit_length()):
        result.append(1 << j)
    return result


def main(x):
    print('Find the factors of a power of 2')
    print('This input number must be a power of 2')
    if is_power_of_2(x):
        print('yes, this is a power of two')
    else:
        print('no, this is not a power of 2')
        return
    start = (round(time.time() * 1000000))
    result = factors_of_power_of_2(x)
    end = (round(time.time() * 1000000))
    print(result)
    print('Factoring took', end - start, 'microseconds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(32)
```

12. We can use a list comprehension instead of a for loop in `powers_of_2_below`.

    ```py
    def powers_of_2_below(x):
        return [1 << j for j in range(x.bit_length())]
    ```

Alternate solutions to `is_power_of_2`:

13. We can use `powers_of_2_below` with `&` and `any`.

    ```py
    def is_power_of_2(x):
        x = abs(x)
        if x == 0:
            return False
        return not any(x & i for i in powers_of_2_below(x - 1))
    ```
14. We can replace the `any` with just `x & x - 1`. This is because \$1000 - 1 = 0111\$. Logically this is doing exactly the same as 13.

    ```py
    def is_power_of_2(x):
        x = abs(x)
        if x == 0:
            return False
        return not x & x - 1
    ```
15. We can instead use `x.bit_length()` to construct the power of 2 it should be and check they are the same.

    ```py
    def is_power_of_2(x):
        if x == 0:
            return False
        return abs(x) == 1 << x.bit_length() - 1
    ```

Overall `is_power_of_2` just doesn't look nice.